# processing html form partway through

Tags: html

Previously, I have seen web forms that are multiple pages long, but on each page, if the inputted information is invalid, it will cause an error and make the user fix their input.

However, I can't seem to find anything to show me how to do this. My form is 2 pages, with a Continue button at the bottom of the first and a Submit button at the bottom of the second. However, all possible errors generated will be on the first page, so I want it to show them if the user hits Continue when he has inputted errors.

Right now, the form is only processed after the user hits Submit and all the data is posted to the backend, which means it then has to go back to the first page to show the errors.

Comment: Search for "form validation javascript"

Comment: What does the continue button do if it doesn't post to the backend?

Comment: It shows the next page of the form...I looked at the javascript form validation, but it says it will only work when the submit button is pressed

Comment: It cannot be handled singled by html only.
What is the motive of putting 2 pages form?

Comment: It is a very long form, and looks better when split into 2 pages. I should clarify...it is not 2 web pages, merely one part of the form (in one div) is displayed at a time, and then when the continue button is pressed, it hides the first part and shows the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check the information every time the user continues to the next input control, and tell him that there's something wrong if he enters any nonsense.

How to achieve this depends on how your form looks:
Does it just contain  and something like that or radio buttons and other "special elements"?

For  you could check at the FocusLost event, but I don't exactly remember its syntax.

Comment: Well, my continue button isn't an input, it is a button showing the next part of the form. It does contain a few radio buttons and checkboxes, but most of it is text.

Do you think it would be best to create two forms and have them dealt with together in the backend? Is that even possible?

Comment: @user3876837 Well, if the biggest part of it is text, just add a FocusLost="Verify(this.value);" event to every field (The method name is just an example). In this method you can then do whatever is necessary for ensuring that the user provided the correct input

Comment: I started doing this when I realized that I don't really want that either. Because they could potentially just not focus the box at all and just press Continue and then it would still work for them. Thus, before showing the next page (when they hit Continue), that is when I need to check to see if the values are valid.

Comment: Then I would also go through all the components and see if one of them is selected (radio button) and if no input field is empty. (Could be done with a simple counter)

Comment: This seems very inefficient for a long form (hundreds of inputs)...is there no other way?

Comment: Maybe if you find a library that can do the task. But this is the only thing that'd come to my mind when I'd have to do something like this.